# prove image of quadratic form is $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a linear space over $\mathbb{R}$. Show if $q:V \to \mathbb{R}$ is quadratic form of rank $n=\dim V$ and there exist non zero vector $v \in V$ such that $q(v)=0$ then $q[V]=\mathbb{R}$.( [] denotes image)

my try: from $rank (q)= n$ we have that matrix of q with respect to some basis have only $1$ or $-1$ at diagonal($0$ else) if we consider an orthornomal basis

I don't know how to involve here vector $v$ to solution

Comment: the word binary is incorrect, in title and second sentence

Comment: what should be instead ?

Comment: binary suggests it has two arguments, it's just called a quadratic form.

Comment: How do you know it will have diagonal format with $\pm1$ values? Once you know that, observe that the condition implies that there must be both $+1$ and $-1$.

Comment: @Berci I think it follows from that q has rank n so $0$ can't be diagonal since then we would have less rank. OK I see that must be both +1 and -1 since consider $v=(x_1,..,x_n)$ then there will be excatly one of them then from $q(v)=0$ we will have that $x_1^2+…+x_n^2=0$ and it's impossible for $(x_1,…,x_n) \neq (0,…,0)$, but what next ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can finish the proof from what you have already found.  Since $q$ is rank $n$ it is of the form:
$$q(v) = x_1^2 + \dots + x_j^2 - x_{j+1}^2 - \dots - x_n^2$$
where $0 \leq j \leq n$.  To be clear, that means any of the signs can be $\pm 1$.  However, since there is a $v \neq 0$ s.t. $q(v) = 0$, then at least one of the signs must be positive and at least one negative:
$$q(v) = 0 = v_1^2 + \dots + v_j^2 - v_{j+1}^2 - \dots - v_n^2$$
where $1 \leq j < n$
Let $$v_+ = (v_1, \dots, v_j, 0, \dots, 0)$$
and $$v_- = (0, \dots, 0, v_{j+1}, \dots, v_{n})$$

Then the image of $q(\lambda v_+)$ is the positive reals and the image of 
$q(\lambda v_-)$ is the negative reals (where $\lambda$ ranges over $(0, \infty]$).

Comment: is there another approach to solve this problem ?